# Should I use Präsens or Präteritum?

Tags: english-to-german

Er erzählte mir, was die Menschen in Afrika brauchen.
Oder
Er erzählte mir, was die Menschen in Afrika brauchten.

Which form is right if I want to use "needed"? Should I use the present form or the past? The translation on DeepL shows the present form. But I couldn't understand why is that so.

Comment: Without context, both can be correct. Please add more details. Hint: the tense shift for reporter speech happens in English, not in German.

Comment: Well the sentence is "He told me what people in Afrika needed."

Answer (score 4):

> Er erzählte mir... (=he told me in the past)

> ...was die Menschen brauchten (what the people needed in the past)
> ...was die Menschen brauchen (what the people still need)

Comment: genaugenommen ist es indirekte Rede, und der Satz müsste lauten "Er erzählte mir, was die Menschen in Afrika bräuchten" bzw... "... gebraucht hätten". Allerdings ist die Formulierung im Indikativ durchaus zulässig, wenn man sich nicht von der Aussage distanzieren möchte.

Comment: @planetmaker: "genaugenommen ist es indirekte Rede" - nur dann, wenn der zweite Satzteil wiedergeben soll, was "er" erzählt hat.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper welche andere Sache solle denn auf ein "Er erzählte mir" folgen?

Comment: @planetmaker: Die Tatsache, von der erzählt wurde.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Das sage ich doch? Auf "Er erzählte" folgt aber - eigentlich - immer indirekte Rede - oder direkte Rede, dann aber mit anderer Interpunktion: Er erzählte: "In Afrika brauchen sie viele Dinge..." - also ganz anders als im OP. Indirekte Rede kann man wie im ersten Kommentar - durch Indikativ ersetzen, wenn man das Erzählte als Tatsache hinnimmt und das Erzählte sich damit (auch) zueigen macht.

Comment: @planetmaker: Ja, im Endeffekt ist das Resultat wohl dasselbe. Ich sehe nur keinen Grund dazu, das dann noch als "indirekte Rede" zu klassifizieren, da in diesem Fall ja eben gerade keine Rede mehr indirekt wiedergegeben wird. Es wird eine Tatsache vermittelt, und zusätzlich wird mitgeteilt, dass "er" genau diese Tatsache auch erwähnt hat. Oder, etwas anders gefragt: Wenn die indirekte Rede nicht genau dazu dient, die (i.A. fremde) Aussage von der eigenen Wahrnehmung/Einschätzung der Tatsachen zu distanzieren, wozu dann?

Comment: Ja, gute Frage: ist es noch indirekte Rede, wenn das Gesagte im Indikativ widergegeben wird?