# Benennung der Konstruktion: indirekte Rede im Indikativ?

Tags: indirect-speech

Bezugnehmend auf die [Frage zur Zeitform](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/67879/should-i-use-pr%C3%A4sens-or-pr%C3%A4teritum), frage ich mich bei der Wiedergabe fremder Aussagen, ob man die Konstruktion anders nennt, abhängig davon, ob man sich die Aussage zu eigen macht (Indikativ) oder nur wiedergibt (Konjunktiv):

Indikativ:

> Er sagte, viele Dinge werden in Afrika anders gehandhabt

Konjunktiv:

> Er sagte, viele Dinge würden in Afrika anders gehandhabt

Meinem Sprachverständnis nach macht man sich mit der indirekten Rede im Konjunktiv die Aussage nicht zueigen. Hingegen kommuniziert man bei der Wiedergabe im Indikativ indirekt, dass man der Aussage zustimmt oder sie für wahr hält. Gibt es eine spezielle Bezeichnung für die Indikativform eines solchen Zitats? Oder ist das (auch) indirekte Rede? Wie bezeichne ich den Unterschied dann?

Answer (score 1):

In der Umgangssprache ist an sich die indirekte Rede ohne Verwendung des Konjunktivs gang und gäbe. Dort wird Konjunktiv eher nicht verwendet (Viele Dialekte z.B. kennen gar keinen Konjunktiv I). Strenggenommen ist das allerdings falsch.

Wer "sauberes Schriftdeutsch" sprechen will, der verwendet Konjunktiv I für die indirekte Rede, außer in folgenden Fällen:

- indirekte Rede wird durch ein "dass" eingeleitet ("Experten behaupten, dass viele Dinge in Afrika anders gehandhabt werden")
- indirekte Rede wird zusätzlich durch "laut" oder "gemäß" markiert ("Gemäß Experten werden in Afrika viele Dinge anders gehandhabt")

(Aber nicht: "Experten behaupten, viele Dinge werden in Afrika anders gehandhabt" - Das wäre strenggenommen falsch)

Deine Aussage, dass man sich durch die Verwendung des Konjunktivs stärker von einer Aussage distanzieren würde, halte ich für fragwürdig. Wo z.B. ist die Distanzierung bei

> Thomas fragte, wer das letzte Klopapier genommen habe.

vs.

> Thomas fragte, wer das letzte Klopapier genommen hat.

(Ich "spüre" keinen Unterschied zwischen den zwei Sätzen, außer dass sich der Indikativ für mich mehr nach Ungangssprache anhört). Der Konjunktiv markiert nur ganz klar, dass es sich um ein Zitat handelt.

Comment: Ich sehe durchaus, dass im vom Dir zitierten Beispiel mit Fragen der Bedeutungsunterschied marginal ist - gerade auch weil es eine Frage der Person keine Tatsache andeutet; auch ich würde den Indikative verwenden. Wenn ich jedoch eine Aussage zitiere, macht es mMn einen kleinen Unterschied, ob ich sie im Indikativ oder Konjunktiv zitiere. Sogar eher in die Richtung Konjunktiv --> ich zweifle am Wahrheitsgehalt der wiedergebenen Aussage. Kann man das 'dass' nicht als Ellipse weglassen bzw. durch Umstellung: "Experten behaupten, viele Dinge würden in Afrika anders gehandhabt"? Klingt ok für mich